# Return rows but filter if there are 1+ rows with the same locationID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table#Appointments:

```
ID, Name, LocationID, Created
```

Currently I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM Appointments
WHERE Created <= @today
ORDER BY ID
```

The problem is, **there are times when there are more than 1 rows for a given
LocationID**, and in this case, I want to return the one with the most current date.

What would the query look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't mention what **version** of SQL Server you're using - but if you're using 2005 or newer, you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME = .........

;WITH LastAppt AS
(
   SELECT 
       ID, Name, LocationID, Created,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LocationID ORDER BY Created DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM dbo.Appointments
   WHERE Created <= @today
)
SELECT 
    ID, Name, LocationID, Created
FROM LastAppt
WHERE RowNum = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

This CTE "partitions" your data by `LocationID`, and for each partition, the `ROW_NUMBER` function hands out sequential numbers, starting at 1 and ordered by `Created DESC` - so the latest row gets `RowNum = 1` (for each `ID`) which is what I select from the CTE in the SELECT statement after it.

Comment: Please note his problem is not actually possible as stated.  Something is being left out.

Comment: Stuff the orignial `ORDER BY ID` line at the end and it should behave as specified.

Comment: @JNK: you're right - but I bet the OP is just formulating the question incorrectly/not clearly enough .... or let him decide if that's what he's looking for - or not.

Comment: @marc_s - I agree, and I think this is a good solution to what we both assume is his problem

Comment: @marc_s can I partition by multiple columns? like SourceID and LocationID?   Since there might be a locationID that has the same ID but different SourceID's (it's not in the db model I wrote initially, but just realized I need to take that into consideration)

Comment: @codecompleting: SURE! `PARTITION BY SourceID,LocationID ...` then you'll get sequential numbers for each pair of `(SourceID,LocationID)`

Answer (score 3):

**The problem you are positing is impossible.**

If your `WHERE` clause specifies:

`WHERE Created = @today`

Then by definition all  your rows will have **IDENTICAL** `Created` fields.

Is there another field you want to use for this?